# I need an alternative to Pligg.com

Tags: deployment, free, social-media

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which Content Management System (CMS) should I use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25745/which-content-management-system-cms-should-i-use)

I was working with Pligg - The Social Networking CMS and it seems like a great software. But there are few things that are not so working well for me. The content scrapper module is not perfect and has lots of bugs.

If anyone knows any other alternatives? All i am trying to do is create DIGG like website.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There is a software called [Drigg](http://drupal.org/project/drigg), which is based on Drupal. However, if you don't know PHP, you may find a Drupal website difficult to set up.

Comment: unfortunately drigg is not maintained anymore.