# Pligg like CMS to create digg like sites

Tags: cms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I need an alternative to Pligg.com](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/1540/i-need-an-alternative-to-pligg-com)

I am trying to find Pligg like CMS that I can use to create Digg like sites. With Pligg, I am not able to import the links automatically. They even have the plug in.

I read about that plugin and it looks it can fetch only from selected sites. I'm not sure how good the plugin is.

I checked out Drigg from Drupal but I don't understand the installation steps properly and I am not able to find documentation on doing this. Can anyone please suggest a CMS like Pligg that can pull bookmarks from other places?

Comment: This is almost an exact duplicate: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/1540/i-need-an-alternative-to-pligg-com

Comment: This looks like a duplicate. It needs to be closed.

Comment: Definitely a duplicate http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/1540/i-need-an-alternative-to-pligg-com

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any other similar scripts, though there may be others. However, if you already have a lot of time invested in Pligg and if Pligg works for you except for that sole feature, IMO your best option would be to hire a developer to work on that plugin to make it function the way you want.